# Shuffling data significantly decrease the performance of linear regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, loss-functions, training-error

I'm trying to build a simple linear regression model $y=ax+b$ using `pytorch`, where $y$ is the number of cells increased on Day $n$ and $x$ is the number of cells increased on Day $n-1$. Both $x$ and $y$ range from 10000 up to 250000 but I did standardize the data before training. The time series of $x$ and $y$ are roughly periodic (as shown in the figure below).

[image]

I have only 100 data points for both $x$ and $y$ and I specified the batch size as 10, the learning rate as 0.001, and the optimizer as SGD. With this setup, I found that if I set `shuffle=True` in `DataLoader`, the performance of the model is much worse.

Specifically, here is the prediction values compared to the true values if `shuffle=False`. The model was doing a decent job, with the loss pretty close to 0.

[image]

However, if I set `shuffle=True` (which I thought was the best practice when training data), the model was far from predictive:

[image]

And the loss fluctuates a lot:

[image]

I wonder the reason for this. Originally I thought shuffling should always be done when training data. Please let me know if I should provide more information. Thank you!

Comment: 1. Your model says that day n is a linear function of day (n-1), but (presuming I understand what you mean by 'shuffle'), when you shuffle, day n and day n-1 are no longer adjacent; you're instead comparing to a randomly selected day, which will have essentially no predictive ability. 2. Your data has a lot of structure that is not present in your model, by the way, you might want to look further afield for good models. e.g. there's a clear weekly seasonality. ... ctd

Comment: ,,,ctd Have you studied any time series? For one example, there are state space models (such as the Basic Structural Model) that might tend to work very well on logs of these data.

Comment: Hi @Glen_b, thanks a lot for the reply! I know there are models that could work much better than linear regression but I was trying to familiarize myself with pytorch with the simplest model.

Comment: (continued) Just to clarify what I mean by shuffling here: I have 100 pairs of data points (x, y), where x is the number of cells increased 1 day before the the date corresponding to y. For example, if the time series of the cells increased for each day is [200, 320, 400, 450, ...], then (x, y) would be (200, 320), (320, 400), (400, 450), .... . After shuffling, the pairs could probably become (320, 400), (400, 450), (200, 320), .... But for each pair, the date corresponding to x data is still adjacent to the date corresponding to y data.

Comment: $n$ is not involved in the model at all. It's just more straightforward if we plot y against n (namely, the time series of y).

Comment: If you're working with sequential data, shouldn't the order matter and shuffling break that inherent relationship?